# CRT _crt_debugger_hook first byte set to 0xcc

Tags: c++, crc32, msvcrt, crt

I'm trying to compare the crc32 hash of my .text section of my exe from the file to the loaded module. I compared the bytes from the file and the loaded module, the only difference was 1 byte and that byte was from a function called `_crt_debugger_hook` the byte on file is `0x83` and in memory is `0xCC`. I don't know what to do. My compiler is `MSVC` and I  have tried using runtime libraries `Multi-Threaded /MT` and `Multi-Threaded DLL /MD`. Compiled to `Release x64`.

Comment: 0xCC means uninitialized stack memory on msvc: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: 0xCC is the INT3 instruction on x86.  It is injected in code when you set a breakpoint with the debugger, that's how a breakpoint works to activate the debugger.

Comment: I forgot to add that it was compiled to x64